# CleverElements / Sendcockpit SOAP API parameters aren't recognized

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm trying to use the CleverElements SOAP API, but I can't get it to work. I have honestly never worked with SOAP (but a lot with [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), etc.), and thought it should be straightforward.

I'm using Ruby with the `savon` gem. I can call any function via SOAP which doesn't need any parameters, but on functions with parameters, the SOAP service doesn't recognize the parameters.

This is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="Sendcockpit/API" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="Sendcockpit/API">
  <env:Header>
    <validate>
      <userid>32027</userid>
      <apikey>**************</apikey>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <mode>live</mode>
    </validate>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <apiGetListDetails>
      <listID>72472</listID>
    </apiGetListDetails>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This is the WSDL file: http://api.sendcockpit.com/server.php?wsdl

Am I missing something (maybe dead simple, super obvious, basic SOAP) stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Apparently I need a wrapping `<ctListRequest>` node. I was under the impression that `savon` applies all things specified by the `wsdl` file...

This request works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="Sendcockpit/API" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="Sendcockpit/API">
  <env:Header>
    <validate>
      <userid>32027</userid>
      <apikey>***********</apikey>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <mode>live</mode>
    </validate>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <apiGetListDetails>
      <ctListRequest>
        <listID>72472</listID>
      </ctListRequest>
    </apiGetListDetails>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```